# How to remove a default program in windows 8/8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I by mistake have chose windows MAIL app as my default program to send mails. So, now if i want to send mail to any one and click on the send email Windows 8 mail app opens automatically. How to remove this default setting? So i could send a mail from chrome browser itself>.

Comment: Have you tried the same method you would for any version of Windows?

Comment: Which method are you talking about?

Comment: This one: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/set-program-access-computer-defaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Click on the Start Button.

2) Type "Default Programs" and select Default Programs from the search bar. On the window that shows up, click on "Set your default programs."

3) In the Programs dropdown bar on the left, select Google Chrome.

4) Select Choose defaults for this program.

5) In the protocols section, put a check next to MAILTO and click Save.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: There is option associate a file type or protocol with the program but it has to many extensions. What's the extension for mail?

Comment: Could you please post a picture

Comment: It should be MAILTO, located in the Protocols section.

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan - This answer doesn't really require a picture.  Its fully documented on the Microsoft website.