# How do you remove a default application for srt files? windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio, video

I have my srt. file set to open up as Windows Media Player, but I want to remove it because I can't add subtitles to my movies because of that.

Comment: Do you want to remove the default application or change it to something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a default program in windows 8/8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/724748/how-to-remove-a-default-program-in-windows-8-8-1)

Comment: This is a X-Y problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change it to another specific program, such as notepad or another editor, you could go to a specific srt file, open it's settings and under `General` change the `Open with` associated program.

If you want to completely remove it, you can remove the relevant entry. Have a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7)